# Firebase read subdirectory in every entry

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get a list of all "Floor" elements in my database. If I use the following database my list should have 3 elements. List should contain the elements with the id's 1234, 4321, 2341.

```
 mydatabase
    -buildings
     --LNBxRoNBhVZyXniqe9t
      ---checked
      ---anzI
      ---anzA
      ---floors
       ----f1
        -----1234
         ------description
         ------id
       ----f2
        -----4321
         ------description
         ------id

     --LXdsafRfasdf12asdfJ
      ---checked
      ---anzI
      ---anzA
      ---floors
       ----f1
        -----2341
         ------description
         ------id
```

> This is my DAO:

```
     private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("buildings");
    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        List<Floors> list = new LinkedList<>();

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        ????
                       }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
           }});
```

Comment: do you have a solution @khaled_bhar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get a list of all "Floor" elements in my Database?

In a very simple way, by iterating the database using `getChildren()` method three times.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference buildingsRef = rootRef.child("buildings");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.child("floors").getChildren()) {
                for(DataSnapshot d : ds.getChildren()) {
                    String key = d.getKey();
                    String description = d.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                    list.add(key);
                    Log.d("TAG", key);
                }
            }
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
buildingsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

> List should contain the elements with the id's 1234, 4321, 2341

The list will contain those exact three ids. If you try to print the list in your logcat, the result will be:

```
[1234, 4321, 2341]
```

Comment: if i want the value of the description i simply do d.child("description").getValue() or ?

Comment: To get the `description`, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to traverse the `DataSnapshot` that you get from Firebase. Something like this

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot buildingSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      for (DataSnapshot floorSnapshot: buildingSnapshot.child("floors").getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot numberSnapshot: floorSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          Log.i(TAG, numberSnapshot.getKey()); // "1234", "4321", "2341"
          Log.i(TAG, ""+numberSnapshot.child("id").getValue());
        }          
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
  }
});
```

Comment: @AlexMamo: thanks for the edit, but I intentionally left the `String.class` off, since the question doesn't show the data type for the `id` property.

Comment: Being an id, I assumed that the property is of type String but you're right, it can be an object of any type. Sorry about that.

Comment: I had `String.class` in there initially, but then noticed that the keys in the question were all numeric (stored as `String` of course, because keys are strings by definition).

Comment: If the `id` property would have been of type number, the concatenation works perfectly while passing `String.class` to the `getValue()` method will produce an exception similar to this: `Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String`. Thanks!